# How can I show hidden files with grep and ls? Problem with period ('.') at the beginning of the word

Tags: grep, regular-expression, ls

I'm trying to display hidden files in the current directory using `grep` and `ls`.

The following command works fine:

`ls -a | egrep '^\.+'`,

but this commands don't work:

`ls -al | egrep '\<\.+'` or `ls -al | egrep '\<[.]+'`.

Does anyone know why the symbol `\<` doesn't work with a period (`.`)?
Btw. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: What do you expect \< to do?

Comment: I think, `\<` should match the regex to the beginning of the word.

Comment: on `GNU grep`, `\<` will match the start of a word, since `.` is not a word character, it will not match in this case... if you want the opposite of word boundary, you can use `\B` but that will also depend on what character is present before the `.`

Comment: @Sundeep, thanks for the explonation.
But now, how to display the file or word with only one `.` at the beginning?

Comment: I'd rather use `ls .[!.]*` instead of piping to grep, see [glob](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob)

Comment: Any reason to avoid `find`? E.g. `find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name '.*'`

Comment: `find` is good to replace these commads, but only for files and directory. 
What if I want to find a word that only has one dot at the beginning?

Answer (score 2):

The *anchor* to the beginning is the caret, so this should work:

```
ls -a | grep '^\.'
```

Comment: Yes, it works and I mentioned it.